# How to add secured layer from ArcGIS service to new map in ArcGIS Pro with C# SDK

Tags: arcgis-pro, c#, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am trying to add a secure layer of an ArcGIS Server. But even with the user / password, ArcGIS Pro shows me a login window to add my layer.

How to get there directly without this login window?

My code information:

```
            CIMInternetServerConnection isc = new CIMInternetServerConnection()
            {
                URL = urlFeature,
                User = "username",
                Password = "password",
                Anonymous = false,
                HideUserProperty = false
            };
            CIMAGSServiceConnection ags = new CIMAGSServiceConnection()
            {
                ServerConnection = isc,
                ObjectName = "Transactions",
                Capabilities = "Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing",
                Description = "",
                ObjectType = "Feature Layer",
                URL = urlFeature
            };
            try
            {
                var layer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateFeatureLayer(ags, map);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show( e.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry..

I found the response:

In my ArcGIS pro addin,

1. Create token for ArcGIS Service.

```
    var url = "https://{baseUrl}/arcgis/tokens/generateToken";
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var postData = "f=JSON";
    postData += "&username={username}";
    postData += "&password={password}";
    postData += "&client=ip";
    postData += "&ip=" + GetLocalIP();
    postData += "&expiration=60";
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
      stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var resString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    return (EsriToken)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(resString, typeof(EsriToken));
```

EsriToken is a class with 2 properties:

```
    public class EsriToken
    {
      public string token { get; set; }
      public string expire { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Set token in Application cookie for Service url:

```
    ProApp.SetCookie(new Uri("https://{baseUrl}/arcgis/services/"), "agstoken=" + token); // token is into EsriToken class...
```

3. Add the featureLayer as secured ArcGIS Service

```
    await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
    {
      map = MapFactory.Instance.CreateMap(title, MapType.Map, MapViewingMode.Map, Basemap.ProjectDefault);
      ServiceConnectionProperties serviceConnectionProperties = new ServiceConnectionProperties(new Uri("https://{baseUrl}/arcgis/services/{YourServicePath}"));
      using (Geodatabase fs_db = new Geodatabase(serviceConnectionProperties))
      {
          IReadOnlyList<TableDefinition> definitions = fs_db.GetDefinitions<FeatureClassDefinition>();
          var dataset_name = "{YourDatasetNameHere}";
          var fc = fs_db.OpenDataset<FeatureClass>(dataset_name);
          try
          {
              var layer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateFeatureLayer(fc, map);
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              throw;
          }
      }
    });
    App.Panes.CreateMapPaneAsync(map);
```

Tadaa... Et voilà !!

Sorry for my English. I'm working on it...